# @OneToMany relationship always return an Empty Set<Object>

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a @OneToMany relationship on the table "Articoli" and a @ManyToOne on the table "Barcode".
Everytime I make a select query on the table named "Articoli" the response returns an "Articoli" json with an empty Set barcode. The set is not null, but the content is always empty.
Anyone can help me please?
Here the code.
Thanks :-)

```
package com.commercioweb.angular.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "articoli")
public class Articoli implements Serializable {
    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "codart")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.Articoli.codArt.Validation}")
    @Size(min = 5, max = 20, message = "{Size.Articoli.codArt.Validation}")
    private String idArticolo;
    
    @Column(name = "descrizione")
    @Size(min = 6, max = 80, message = "{Size.Articoli.descrizione.Validation}")
    private String descrizione;
    
    @Column(name = "um")
    private String unitaMisura;
    
    @Column(name = "codstat")
    private String codStat;
    
    @Column(name = "pzcart")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.Articoli.pzcart.Validation}")
    private Integer pezziPerCartone;
    
    @Column(name = "pesonetto")
    private double pesoNetto;
    
    @Column(name = "idstatoart")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.Articoli.idStatoArt.Validation}")
    private String idStatoArticolo;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "datacreazione")
    private Date dataCreazione;
    
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "articolo", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Barcode> barcode;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idiva", referencedColumnName = "idiva")
    private Iva iva;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idfamass", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private FamigliaAssortimento famigliaAssortimento;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "articolo", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Ingredienti ingredienti;

    public String getIdArticolo() {
        return idArticolo;
    }

    public void setIdArticolo(String idArticolo) {
        this.idArticolo = idArticolo;
    }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public String getUnitaMisura() {
        return unitaMisura;
    }

    public void setUnitaMisura(String unitaMisura) {
        this.unitaMisura = unitaMisura;
    }

    public String getCodStat() {
        return codStat;
    }

    public void setCodStat(String codStat) {
        this.codStat = codStat;
    }

    public Integer getPezziPerCartone() {
        return pezziPerCartone;
    }

    public void setPezziPerCartone(Integer pezziPerCartone) {
        this.pezziPerCartone = pezziPerCartone;
    }

    public double getPesoNetto() {
        return pesoNetto;
    }

    public void setPesoNetto(double pesoNetto) {
        this.pesoNetto = pesoNetto;
    }

    public String getIdStatoArticolo() {
        return idStatoArticolo;
    }

    public void setIdStatoArticolo(String idStatoArticolo) {
        this.idStatoArticolo = idStatoArticolo;
    }

    public Date getDataCreazione() {
        return dataCreazione;
    }

    public void setDataCreazione(Date dataCreazione) {
        this.dataCreazione = dataCreazione;
    }

    public Set<Barcode> getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }

    public void setBarcode(Set<Barcode> barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }

    public Iva getIva() {
        return iva;
    }

    public void setIva(Iva iva) {
        this.iva = iva;
    }

    public FamigliaAssortimento getFamigliaAssortimento() {
        return famigliaAssortimento;
    }

    public void setFamigliaAssortimento(FamigliaAssortimento famigliaAssortimento) {
        this.famigliaAssortimento = famigliaAssortimento;
    }

    public Ingredienti getIngredienti() {
        return ingredienti;
    }

    public void setIngredienti(Ingredienti ingredienti) {
        this.ingredienti = ingredienti;
    }
    
    
    

}
```

```
package com.commercioweb.angular.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "barcode")
public class Barcode implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id()
    @Column(name = "barcode")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.Barcode.barcode.Validation}")
    @Size(min = 8, max = 13, message = "{Size.Barcode.barcode.Validation}")
    private String barcode;
    
    @Column(name = "idtipoart")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.Barcode.idTipoArt.Validation}")
    private String idTipoArticolo;
    
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "codart", referencedColumnName = "codart")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Articoli articolo;

    public String getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }

    public void setBarcode(String barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }

    public String getIdTipoArticolo() {
        return idTipoArticolo;
    }

    public void setIdTipoArticolo(String idTipoArticolo) {
        this.idTipoArticolo = idTipoArticolo;
    }

    public Articoli getArticolo() {
        return articolo;
    }

    public void setArticolo(Articoli articolo) {
        this.articolo = articolo;
    }

}
```

```
package com.commercioweb.angular.controller;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.commercioweb.angular.entity.Articoli;
import com.commercioweb.angular.exception.BindingException;
import com.commercioweb.angular.exception.DuplicateException;
import com.commercioweb.angular.exception.NotFoundException;
import com.commercioweb.angular.service.ArticoliService;
import com.commercioweb.angular.utils.ResponseInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
@CrossOrigin(value = "http://localhost:4200")
public class ArticoliController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ArticoliService articoloService;
    
    @Autowired
    private ResourceBundleMessageSource errMessage;

    @GetMapping(value = "/findarticolo/id/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Articoli> findById(@PathVariable(name = "id") String idArticolo) throws NotFoundException{
        
        Optional<Articoli> articoloOp = articoloService.findById(idArticolo);
        
        Articoli articolo = articoloOp.get();
        
        if(articolo == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException("Articolo non trovato con id "+idArticolo);
        }
        
        if(articolo.getBarcode().isEmpty()) 
            System.out.println("BARCODE SET IS EMPTY");
        
        articolo.getBarcode().forEach(b -> System.out.println(b));
        
        ResponseEntity<Articoli> response = new ResponseEntity<Articoli>(articolo, HttpStatus.OK);
        
        return response;
        
    }
}
```

I was expecting a set of one or more Barcode objects in the Set barcode property

Comment: Are you sure there are related barcodes in your database stored? The problem might be that there are entities unexpectedly deleted because of the orphanRemoval settings

Comment: Yes I'm sure, in my database every Articoli object is reated to one or more barcodes

Comment: Did you, by any chance, add any extra modules to Jackson, apart from the default config?